# How to get HTML 5 input type range with string values

Tags: html

I need HTML 5 slider with three text value instead of integer. for example one I need following three value in slider.

likely
  unlikely 
  very likely

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you the HTML input you want:
`<input type="range" min="1" max="3" value"1" class="slider" id="myRange">`

From there you could put text above/below it for display purposes. You'd simply save the integer as a value, or change it to text server-side.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you wouldn't mind, could you please select this as the accepted answer? Thanks!